# I want to show the percentage in progress bar and this progress bar is shown within the modal. The value of the percentage is coming from backend

Tags: javascript, java, html, jquery

enter code hereI have written the code for fetching the value of percentage(amount of data inserted) from the backend using ajax call. I want to show the value of percentage within progressbar and this progressbar is within modal pop-up.
But somehow my jquery code isn't working. Even the document.ready function isn't working. If anyone can help me with this!`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  alert("entered");
  initializeModal();
});

function initializeModal() {
  $('#myModal').modal({
    backdrop: 'static',
    keyboard: false,
    show: false
  });

  $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
    console.log("modalfunction");
    function fetchpercentage() {
      $.ajax({
        url: '/progress',
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
          console.log(data.num);
          $("#dynamic")
            .css("width", data.num + "%")
            .attr("aria-valuenow", data.num)
            .text(data.num + "% Complete");
          if (data.num >= 100) {
            clearInterval(interval);
            document.getElementById('complete').innerHTML = "Uploaded";
          }
        }
      });
    }
    console.log("");
    var interval = setInterval(fetchpercentage, 3000);
  });

  $('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
    // reset modal
    if ($('#myModal').data('reenable')) {
      $(this).removeData();
      $('#myModal').modal({
        show: true
      });
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Progress Bar Starting -->

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title in" id="myModalLabel">Please Wait</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body center-block">
        <div class="progress">
          <div id="dynamic" class="progress-bar progress-bar-success progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 0%">
            <span id="current-progress"></span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <span id="complete"></span>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default hide" data-dismiss="modal" id="btnClose">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->
```

This is my servlet code -

```java
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Random random = new Random();
    for (int j = 0; j <= 99; j++) {
        int num = random.nextInt(100);
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        obj.put("progress", num);
        //response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.getWriter().write(json.toString());
    }
```

Comment: Check your console log for errors. Update your question with the log so we can see how far your code has reached without errors. You can replace the `alert` with a console log call too.

Comment: There's no error in the console!! That's what the problem is

Comment: Yes, but successful log calls would still print and indicate how far the code runs before it errors out. I'm referring to the browser console log btw, not the IDE one.

Comment: I have added the image of my output. Take a look and help me if you can figure this out

Comment: Check the <script> tag loading the jQuery. Since the alert isn't firing, maybe the jQuery URL isn't correct. Update the question with full html source code, it'll be easy to spot any errors.

Comment: I have added the script tags

Comment: You need a <script> tag for jQuery as well. That's why your JS code isn't running. Add jQuery, then Bootstrap, then Popper just before </body> and when the scripts get setup correctly the alert should fire.